# Scale on scroll

Tags: javascript

I have a horizontal scrolling, and **while** scrolling I would like to scale the images up and down to get some effect.

So with this scroller :

```
<div class="scroller" id="scroller">
    <div class="galleryPhoto">
        <div class="Photo" id="Photo1" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/700/1200);"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="galleryPhoto">
        <div class="Photo" id="" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800/1200);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting this callback but it won't scale, not matter what number I put there.

```
$("#scroller").on("scroll", function (e) {
    let horizontal = e.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
    let vertical = e.currentTarget.scrollTop;
    var box = document.getElementById('Photo1');

    var x = screen.width;

    console.log(1 - (horizontal / x));
    box.scale = (1.5, 1.5);
});
```

Comment: Did you miss a closing `</div>` tag? or is it just not copied to the question?

Comment: No, just copy the code fast to show case what I do. It works and scroll , just won't scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parallax](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) effects. there are some options for scrolling you can use it.